# Code generated from Postman does not work - body format in request is actually different

Tags: python, postman

I build a REST API in Flask and tested it with Postman. Now I want to get a script which i can modify myself. Therefore I generated the script for Python and well, it doesn't work.

In Postman I send a key-value pair under the form-data tab. It works, request parser can find the string and proceed using it.

The generated code looks like this, and I think it makes totally sense (I removed the URL):

```
import requests
import json

url = "..."
payload = {'apikey': '1234567891' }
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

To actually show the format, I added an log handler which logs every request I send to Flask:

```
@app.before_request
def log_request_info():
    app.logger.info('Headers: %s', request.headers)
    app.logger.info('Body: %s', request.get_data())
```

When I send a request with Postman GUI, this is the logged request:

```
Body: b'----------------------------222811375002090327791056\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="apikey"\r\n\r\n1234567891\r\n----------------------------222811375002090327791056--\r\n'
```

This is the request I see using the script:

```
Body: b'apikey=1234567891'
```

Where does the difference come from, and why do not both version work? When adding the apikey to the reqparser, I didn't even specify the location of the data (just the name, required=True, helptext and custom validator)